# Laravel 5.7 global functions handle ajax in every controllers

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, global

I have a couple of functions which i use in all controllers like this:

```
//ajax
public function region()
{
    return Region::all();
}
//ajax
public function provinces(Request $request)
{

    if(!empty($request->input('region_select')))
    {
        $id_region = $request->input('region_select');

        return Region::find($id_region)->Provinces;

    }
    else{

        return Province::all();
    }

}
```

Is it correct to extend the base controller with these functions to have them available globally? 
Or is there a safer and more elegant approach?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you need this function to work on ajax need `return response()->json(['region'=> Region:all()])`

Comment: no, the question is where i put these functions, if i want it's available in all controllers?